# How to diagnose a NullPointerException where the stacktrace never goes through my code?

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a tab pane that has four children tabs. The user can add and remove tabs using a context menu. Sometimes, at apparently unpredictable times, when adding and removing tabs, I get a NullPointerException that never seems to pass through my code.  Accordingly, I'm having trouble diagnosing it.  Any idea where I can start aside from slowly stripping out code in a test project until the error goes away?

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser.processOffer(PickResultChooser.java:185)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser.offer(PickResultChooser.java:143)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.intersects(Node.java:5219)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$1.intersects(Node.java:543)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.intersects(NodeHelper.java:258)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3161)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doPickNodeLocal(Parent.java:817)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$500(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doPickNodeLocal(Parent.java:131)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(ParentHelper.java:108)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:3993)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:2029)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.access$6800(Scene.java:172)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3805)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser.processOffer(PickResultChooser.java:185)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser.offer(PickResultChooser.java:143)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.intersects(Node.java:5219)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$1.intersects(Node.java:543)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.intersects(NodeHelper.java:258)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3161)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Region.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:803)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doPickNodeLocal(Parent.java:817)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$500(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doPickNodeLocal(Parent.java:131)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(ParentHelper.java:108)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5192)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:3993)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:2029)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.access$6800(Scene.java:172)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3805)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: You can start off with reporting this to the JavaFX list of issues. Of course with a sample to reproduce.

Comment: This seems related to how JavaFX is trying to determine what nodes are eligible for mouse events in the scene graph. You can start troubleshooting by removing all nodes that are not at the points that you clicked. If your click is on a context menu, then I'm clueless why that happens. Also, try this on JavaFX 8 to see if it happens - they have shifted/modified the codes when they were trying to remove the `impl_...()` methods.

Comment: Please see this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353055/unexplained-nullpointerexception-in-javafx-application